# how to delete values less than greatest correlating to other value in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have several workarounds for this and they all tend to be a PITA.

So, here is some stuff:

```
create table things1 (num1 int, num2 int); 
create table things2 like things1;

insert into things1 values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1);
```

So, I want to see the max values of num2 for each num1.

Here it is:

```
select e.num1
     , e.num2 
  from
    (select *
            , row_number() over (partition by num1 order by num2 desc) rnum 
        from things1
     ) e 
 where e.rnum = 1;
+------+------+
| num1 | num2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    3 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

There it is.

Now I want to delete the values less than the max.

Which values?

```
select e.num1
     , e.num2 
  from 
     ( select *
            , row_number() over (partition by num1 order by num2 desc) rnum 
         from things1
     ) e 
 where e.rnum > 1;
+------+------+
| num1 | num2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

These are the values I want to delete.

Can I delete them?

```
delete e from (select *
           , row_number() over (partition by num1 order by num2 desc) rnum 
           from things1
     ) e 
 where e.rnum > 1;

ERROR 1288 (HY000): The target table e of the DELETE is not updatable
```

This is just lame.

I can put those values I want to delete out into another table. Then, when I want to delete based on them, I get the same kind of error.

So, I can write out the values I want to delete and pass them to another mysql instance and they will get deleted. I can even create a stored procedure to delete them and pass the values that I want to delete and they will get deleted.

But can I just not jump through these stupid hoops. Please?

Comment: Note that the yada yada is the important bit (q.f Seinfeld)

Comment: And incidentally, it's often quicker to create a new table, retaining just the rows you want to keep.

Comment: yes, Strawberry was right. But even a "correct" call to delete does not work. Edited

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2Zzj8XHiGeg7vvqTu8aQ/0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment.  I see that the subquery is not allowed in both the FROM and the WHERE clause, so we need to use a regular join here.

```
delete t
from things1 t
join things1 futureRecords using (num1)
where t.num2 < futureRecords.num2;
```

Comment: mysql> delete t from things1 t where exists (select 1 from things1 a where a.num1 = t.num1 and a.num2 > t.num2);
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry I didn't test before submitting